# Realizing special case of a class in UML and SQL

Tags: sql, database, uml

In an application, that allows registered users to create pages which can be edited by other registered users, what is the correct way of distinguishing a normal user from the creator of the page, both in UML and SQL.

In UML, I have

```
--------  accesible by --------  
| Page |  ------------ |User  |
--------               --------
  |created by            / \
  |                       | 
  |                       |
---------   is a          |
|Creator|------------------
---------
```

Now, I don't think this is the correct UML. So, what would be the correct UML representation of what I am trying to express. And eventually, I would like to create SQL database for the same. In that case, what would the Database Schema look like?

Comment: other registered user can also create page or they are authorize only to edit the details?

Comment: @amitesh All users can create a page. But if a user creates a page, then he will have some administrative privileges over that page such as which other users can edit the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always you have multiple possibilities - for Model (UML) and Code (SQL, or whatever).

Model A) like you depicted above
Model B) Only a User class, no Creator. User is target of both associations from Page: 'accessible by' and 'created by'

The difference between the models is that you can distinguish between users who can create pages and those who cannot in Model A. Model B only allows to distinguish users who already have created pages and those who have not.

Both models might be implemented by both implementations.

Code 1) Use 5 tables: Page, User, Creator, PageToUser, PageToCreator
Code 2) Use 4 tables: Page, User, PageToUserAccessible, PageToUserCreated (and possibly a flag 'creator' in User)
Code 3) Use 3 tables: Page, User, PageToUser and a flag "created" in PageToUser (plus possibly a flag "creator" in User)

Got it? Everything is 'correct' - It's up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case your role should be specific means roles should be different with different access.
Suppose i have three user withh different access for each role.
1 Admin
2 Manager
3 User
In this case admin can create page and have access to edit all details of the page and user, whereas manager have access to create page and to edit few details of that page according to access.
user have access only to create and view the page not to edit the details of the page.
Access level should be defined in the database.

I hope this will help you